# Conway's Steiner-Lehmus proof of nonexistence of a direct proof?

Tags: geometry

First of all, here's the link to Conway's piece:
http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2004-August/008394.html

Now Conway supposedly states that you can't have a direct proof of Steiner-Lehmus since you'd have to argue that side lengths of a triangle are positive. But all the lengths of the triangle are just multiples of an arbitrary unit length, so they're all positive, right?

I don't see what's so "not direct" about assuming that lengths are positive.

Comment: Conway does not state that there is "no direct proof".

Comment: What is his claim then? Why do people say that Conway did indeed prove that?

Comment: Where is this stated?

Comment: The wikipedia page for the theorem seems to say that proving that side lengths are positive is not direct ("But this may not be considered direct as one must first argue about why the other factor cannot be 0"). I guess this isn't what Conway is saying (I guess a lot of sites are misrepresenting it then), but basically I don't understand how proving this positivity can't be direct.